# r hms() converts negative values to positive (but shouldn't)

Tags: r

I have a character variable `time` like "hh:mm:ss" consisting of positive values and negative values "-hh:mm:ss". I want to convert it into a variable I can calculate with so I thought it would be best to convert it into seconds. Later I want to calculate with the results. Add them, multiply them, have means and so on.

For example I have this data in the time variable (as character):

```r
 -00:00:01 -00:00:02 -00:00:07 00:00:00 00:00:01 00:00:02 00:00:03 
  00:00:04 00:00:05 00:00:06 00:00:07 00:00:08 00:00:09 00:00:10 
  00:00:11 00:00:12 00:00:13 00:00:14 00:00:15 00:00:16 00:00:17
  00:00:18 00:00:19 00:00:20
```

I wanted to convert it into `hms` and then into seconds, so I tried this:

```
df$time1<- hms(df$time)
df$time_sec <- period_to_seconds(df$time1)
```

The result is not that bad: at the end I have got a integer variable `time_sec` I can calculate with. But... after the first step my negative values are lost and have converted into positive values..
damn.

I found the information that actually `hms` should be able to recognize a minus as negative time. But actually it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The `hms` documentation is confusing (at least to me), so confusing that I'm tempted to open an issue.

> ‘hms()’ recognizes all non-numeric characters except '-' as separators ('-' is used for negative ‘durations’)

However, this apparently **does not** mean that `-HH:MM:SS` works as one would expect: see [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/511). Instead, the behaviour is something like this:

```r
library(lubridate)
all.equal(hms("3-3-3"), hours(3) - minutes(3) - seconds(3))  ## TRUE
```

In other words, in your case the negative sign is applied only to the hours component, which is zero anyway (!)

```r
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

x <- scan(text="-00:00:01 -00:00:02 -00:00:07 00:00:00 00:00:01 00:00:02 00:00:03 
  00:00:04 00:00:05 00:00:06 00:00:07 00:00:08 00:00:09 00:00:10 
  00:00:11 00:00:12 00:00:13 00:00:14 00:00:15 00:00:16 00:00:17
  00:00:18 00:00:19 00:00:20", what = character(1))

neg_per <- function(x) {
    (hms(x)
        %>% period_to_seconds()
        %>% ifelse(grepl("^-", x), -., .)
    )
}
neg_per(x)
##  [1] -1 -2 -7  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```